# PyMC3 fitting quadratic line to data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pymc3

How do you choose quadratic model parameters? This is what I've got so far ..
with pm.Model() as quad_model:
#I'd like to add sigmas (and mu if that's reasonable) but I'm not sure how to decide how big to go..

```
a = pm.Normal('a')
b = pm.Normal('b')
c = pm.Normal('c')

sigma = pm.HalfNormal('scatter', sd=sigm_y)
```

#this .MutableData I'm not sure I'm using correct, I'm following an #example but my data is position not  dates/time

```
t = pm.MutableData('t', bp_rp, dims='obs_time')
mu = a*t**2 + b*t + c

obs = pm.Normal('mg', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=mg, dims='obs_time')#, dims='obs_time'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, can you iterate what exactly isn't working as expected?

Comment: If asking about how to choose priors or other methodological aspects, then the question would be better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [the PyMC Discourse](https://discourse.pymc.io).